# Particle count inside Volume using Geometry Nodes

Tags: particles, geometry-nodes

Can I create a live counter of how many particles are in a given volume at any given frame. I've seen a similar answer for Animation nodes but as far as I can tell those are no longer in blender.

Using molecular+ to generate the particles if that matters.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean like the Point value in the Spreadsheet window?

Comment: animation nodes was never a part of blender. It is still a free add-on which still works, so if that worked earlier for you - i would assume it would work now too ;) and if i could guess ( but i am not sure) but i don't think that GN can do this at the current state of development.

Comment: @3pointedit I mean the number of particles passing through the cube in 3d space. Currently though the point value shows 0 even though there are particles on screen.

Comment: @Chris Oh I see, I thought it was an outdated version of Geometry nodes. I guess I will need to install that perhaps.

Comment: there is geometry nodes (which comes with Blender and will be developed still) and there is animation nodes (which is a free add-on) and i am pretty sure that you can get the number of particles by the particle info node in animation nodes - but of course you would have to get the positions too and check whether they are inside your cube